# Get JSON response from PHP file with OkHttp

Tags: java, php, android

I need to make simple JSON request from PHP file which is on my localhost server. PHP code executes smoothly and it looks like:

```
<?php

header('Content-type: application/json');

$db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=nadjiprijevoz;charset=utf8', 'root', '');

$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);

$query = "Select * FROM rute";

try {

    $stmt = $db->prepare($query);
    $result = $stmt->execute();

} catch(PDOException $ex) {

    // Greska kod izvodjenja querija 
    $response["success"] = 0;
    $response["message"] = "Database Error!";
    die(json_encode($response));

}

$rows = $stmt->fetchAll();

if($rows) {

    $response["success"] = 1;
  $response["message"] = "Rute dohvacene";
  $response["rute"] = array();

  foreach($rows as $row) {
    $ruta = array();
    $ruta["id"] = $row["id"];
    $ruta["naziv"] = $row["naziv"];
    $ruta["polaziste"] = $row["polaziste"];
    $ruta["odrediste"] = $row["odrediste"];

    array_push($response["rute"] , $ruta);
  }

  echo json_encode($response);

} else {

    $response["success"] = 0;
    $response["message"] = "Nema ruta";
    die(json_encode($response));

}

?>
```

When i try to fetch JSON data with my android application i dont get any response from the PHP file. Im using OkHttp library for fetching response and until now it worked smoothly (i havent been using php files before, only pure json) but when i try to get php response it doesnt work. Main activity code looks like:

```
public class activityMain extends ActionBarActivity {

    private final static String TAG = activityMain.class.getSimpleName();
    Ruta[] mRute;

    @InjectView(R.id.textView) TextView text1;
    @InjectView(R.id.textView2) TextView text2;
    @InjectView(R.id.textView3) TextView text3;

    String redditUrl = "http://localhost/nadjiprijevoz/connect.php";


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.layout_mainmenu);
        ButterKnife.inject(this);

        OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
        Request request = new Request.Builder()
                .url(redditUrl)
                .build();

        Call call = client.newCall(request);

        call.enqueue(new Callback() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(Request request, IOException e) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onResponse(Response response) throws IOException {
                try {

                    String jsonData = response.body().string();
                    Log.i(TAG, response.body().string());

                    if (response.isSuccessful()) {

                        mRute = parsePostDetails(jsonData);

                        text1.setText(mRute[0].getNaziv());
                        text2.setText(mRute[0].getPolaziste());
                        text3.setText(mRute[0].getOdrediste());

                    }
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Excepiton caught: " , e);
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Excepiton caught: " , e);
                }

            }
        });

    }

    private Ruta[] parsePostDetails(String jsonData) throws JSONException {

        JSONObject rutaObjectJSON = new JSONObject(jsonData);
        JSONArray rutaArrayJSON = rutaObjectJSON.getJSONArray("rute");

        Ruta[] ruteTemp = new Ruta[rutaArrayJSON.length()];

        for (int i = 0; i < ruteTemp.length; i++) {

            JSONObject rutaDetailJSON = rutaArrayJSON.getJSONObject(i);

            Ruta tempRuta = new Ruta();

            tempRuta.setNaziv(rutaDetailJSON.getString("naziv"));
            tempRuta.setOdrediste(rutaDetailJSON.getString("odrediste"));
            tempRuta.setPolaziste(rutaDetailJSON.getString("polaziste"));

            ruteTemp[i] = tempRuta;

        }

        return ruteTemp;
    }


}
```

Does anyone know where am i making mistake, if you do i would be very thankful.

Comment: Is your app crashing or are you just not getting any response?

Comment: If you have been using json and php is ur only change then its clear that the problem (probably) is with php. Could you test your web service and ensure its returning the desired json format? More so, could you show us a sample response?

Comment: App is not crashing ... im just not getting any response.

Comment: When i log out response.body().string() i dont get anything so obvious problem i assume is with php ... and php is not my primary language ( i know the basics but im not really an expert in it ) but i dont understand why it wouldnt work because when i run my connect.php script i get json response on page with all needed information

Comment: Send a request to your PHP server from a browser or Postman. Are you getting the response? Also, aren't you getting anything in your logcat either?

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/7XQGbW6.jpg?1
this is my connect.php when i run it ( it shows JSON code ) 
logcat is empty when i try to log out fetched data with response.body().string()

Comment: I see that your PHP server is running on your localhost. Localhost wont be recognized by your Android device. It's an internal server that only your computer can recognize. That is why you can get response on your browser. Configure your PHP to run on the IP Address of your computer and then try connecting to that IP Address inside your Android code.

Comment: i switched connect.php now to my server and now app chashes when i run it

Comment: it all works now ... forgot to switch port ... TY :)